# Changing theme colors of Material Design Lite in scss

Tags: css, colors, sass, material-design-lite

I installed material design lite module through npm, but I want to change it with other colors and preferably with colors that are not included in Material Design Color Pallete.

I read here [Here on GitHub how to do it](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/wiki/Customizing-Colors).

But it doesn't work for me, when I try to change color I get white/black color look.

I have in my main scss

```
@import 'colors';
@import '../../../node_modules/material-design-lite/src/material-design-lite'; `
```

And my _colors.scss contains:

```
$golden: #c6a259;
$brown: #240000;
$color-primary: #c6a259 !default;
$color-primary-dark: #c6a259 !default;
$color-accent: #240000 !default;
$color-primary-contrast: #240000 !default;
$color-accent-contrast: #240000 !default;
```

The difference you can see in image below (Before and after I changed values of color varaibles).[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with looking at the generated CSS.

Try to remove the `!default`.

And use RGB color string:`"255, 0, 0"`

For example for red as primary color.

```
 $color-primary: "255, 0, 0";
```