# How to use Custom colors with Material Design Lite?

Tags: css, themes, material-design, material-design-lite

I am new to Material Design Lite. I want to use a custom color scheme, particularly the *primary color* and *accent color.*

I have seen their [theme builder tool](https://getmdl.io/customize/index.html), but it **only offers a few colors.**

How can I do that? How can I use custom (primary and accent) colors (which are not included in their theme builder tool) in my site, which uses Material Design Lite?

Answer (score 4):

by now there is a way to do this, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980934/changing-theme-colors-of-material-design-lite-in-scss) (including the fixes in the answer).

In short: (the following lines were taken and fixed from that question, but I didn't test them myself)

scss:

```
@import 'colors';
@import '../../../node_modules/material-design-lite/src/material-design-lite'; `
```

_colors.scss:

```
$color-primary: "255, 0, 0";
$color-accent: "0, 0, 255";
```

[Github reference](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/wiki/Customizing-Colors)

Answer (score 2):

i reckon there is no out-of-the-box way to achieve this.

I guess we may have to tinker around`_color_definitions.scss` which has pre-defined colors as selected in the theme-picker ,like

```
$palette-red:
"255,235,238"
"255,205,210"
"239,154,154"
"229,115,115"
"239,83,80"
"244,67,54"
"229,57,53"
"211,47,47"
"198,40,40"
"183,28,28"
"255,138,128"
"255,82,82"
"255,23,68"
"213,0,0";
```

or build your own sass rules to generate required custom theme.